# Class not found exception when trying to run JAR file with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am following [Spark Quick Start tutorial page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html)

I reached the last point, compiled my file to a `JAR` that should be ready to go.

Running my application from the terminal:

`spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local[4] /usr/local/spark/target/scala-2.11`

Gives the following error:

```
2018-10-07 20:29:17 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, test-ThinkPad-X230 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 172.17.147.32 instead (on interface wlp3s0)
2018-10-07 20:29:17 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2018-10-07 20:29:17 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-10-07 20:29:18 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-10-07 20:29:18 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-08d94e7e-ae24-4892-a704-727a6caa1733
```

Why won't it find my SimpleApp class? I've tried giving it the full path. My `SimpleApp.scala` is in my root Spark folder, `/usr/local/spark/`

Comment: You have to point directly to your .jar. Previously you should have built it using sbt package as tutorial indicates.

Comment: I've done so and it works! Seems like ive missed it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Best way to deploy your app to spark is to use sbt [assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin. It will create a fat jar that contains all your dependencies. After packaging your app you have to point spark to the jar directly.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Spark JAR in your spark submit. A spark-submit submit looks as below:

> ./bin/spark-submit 
>     --class  
>     --master  
>     --deploy-mode

application-jar is the JAR file that you have build.

Hope this helps :)